# Endless loop on fb authentication

Tags: php, facebook

Trying to pull out simple authentication, gives me endless loop.

strangest thing, when using Mixed js and Php api, it works.

```
    <?Php
//uses the PHP SDK.  Download from https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk
require 'src/facebook.php';


$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '306597542762982',
  'secret' => '88XXXXXXf1',
));


if(!$facebook->getUser())
    header("location: ".$facebook->getLoginUrl ());

var_dump($facebook->getUser());
```

The above code gives me endless loop.
BUT! if you removed the header redirection, and I use the js sdk only for the login process, it works.

Comment: can you paste your var_dump result of $facebook->getUser() ?

Comment: Ok. can you paste what you are getting in $facebook->getLoginUrl () ?

Comment: string(145) "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=306597542762982&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fv2.raal.co.il%2F&state=3c1558c4c8494d327989371cbb341451"

Comment: Are you in an app canvas or a fan page tab?

Comment: OMG. I fear... did you try removing all whitespaces (it looks like you have a <Tab> there) before `<?Php` ? Would you please try that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before ANYTHING, make sure you have the latest SDK.  I've seen this behavior using an outdated SDK.  And the comment in your code points to a deprecated version.  Make sure your code is from https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk and not from https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk as it says in your comment.

Also, you are skipping a couple of steps that you can see in the [examples from Facebook on github](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php).  Try doing it exactly like they are.

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}
```

And then

```
if (!$user) {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
  header("Location: " . $loginUrl);
}
```

I'm still not positive that `header` will work, so you might also want to try using a javascript redirect:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
```

Comment: What part of it worked? Did you just use the code I provided or did you get the latest SDK?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** Ok, thats not the problems solution, sorry

As far as I understand it, the header is set, but the script is not stopped. Imagine a different header (not `Location`), it would be bad if the script was stopped then. So try the following:

```
if(!$facebook->getUser()) {
    header("location: ".$facebook->getLoginUrl ());
    die();
}
```

HTH

Comment: Ok, why do I get an upvote for an answer, that doesn't answer the question? :)

Comment: Its impossible to say if its correct for OP but if you have things going on after the header() then it could be - worked for me